# Long string convert to UTF-8 throws exception

Tags: java, gwt

I am using GWT, and have a very long string from RichTextArea and I want to convert it to UTF-8 before sending to the server:

```
String content = new String(rta.getText().getBytes(), "UTF-8");
```

However this one throws an exception saying:

```
 [Range Error]: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

Is this a bug?

Comment: I don't think that line of code is causing this error.

Comment: Call stack size error is almost always caused by a memory leak, like an endless loop.

Comment: @JamesB The log says this line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[RichTextArea.getText](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/RichTextArea.html#getText()) returns a `String`. The operation you are doing to "convert to utf-8" is not correct. There is no need to convert a java `String` to any character encoding. The code you have is getting the bytes in the default character encoding of the platform and then interpreting them as utf-8. At best this is a lot of work to get back to the exact same `String`. At worst (say platform encoding of utf-16le) you mangle your `String` data completely.